# Can someone help Scott Manley explain this Snoopy-capturing maneuver?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, delta-v, snoopy

In his recent video [Apollo 10's Lunar Module Snoopy Is Lost In Space - Could We Bring it Home?](https://youtu.be/jXVYZm9epmU?t=578) Scott Manley uses some fancy supplemental techniques in KSP to simulate and explain a possible mission to capture [Snoopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snoopy#In_aviation_and_space) (Apollo 10 Lunar Module) "...[and returning him safely to the Earth.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_choose_to_go_to_the_Moon)"

But at about `09:38` Manley surprisingly finds himself at a bit of a loss for words. This explanation says little more than "it takes less Delta V because you square it and so it takes less Delta V":

> Now when you’re doing capture from deep space, you want to get down close to the Earth, because that way you’re actually using Earth’s gravity to reduce the amount of Delta V you need to perform the capture.
>
> If Earth wasn’t there, you’d actually need more Delta V to match the orbit, because you fall down into it you get this square law where you’re adding your velocity squared, and… listen, it’s just a simple thing to do. You drop down into the gravity well and then you perform your burn there and then it becomes… it means you need less Delta V to perform this.

**Question:** Can someone help Scott Manley out and explain more clearly what it is that he's trying to explain?

cued at `09:38`

Comment: Sounds like it taught him the orbital mechanics *apart from the vocabulary* just fine.

Comment: Scott Manley studied Astrophysics. He definitely knows what he is talking about, he just doesn’t want to give a lengthy explanation that most people would not understand and make them just annoyed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oberth effect for Earth vehicles](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4229/oberth-effect-for-earth-vehicles)

Comment: I do not mean to be overly defensive here, but according to [His bio on the B612 foundation homepage](https://b612foundation.org/members/scott-manley/) ”Scott spent a decade in academia studying astrophysics and computational physics at the University of Glasgow and Armagh Observatory where he focused on small bodies in the solar system and specifically the probabilities of collision.”, so he most definitely knows what he is talking about.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is about the Oberth Effect. It however is notoriously difficult to explain and wrap head around. I think the two big answers on that linked question explain it pretty good. A at least don’t think I can explain it in such a way that anyone else can understand it.

Comment: I have. I think this situation is about a combination of gravity assists and the oberth effect (which is specifically about maneuvers at higher velocities and close to planets). I however don’t really have the rime right now to write a good answer for that.

Comment: Does voting to close a question prevent other people from answering it? The question is not officially closed yet. If the community decides it should be closed it will be closed. If not other people can still answer it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's talking about the Oberth effect - I've heard him describe it similarly before in previous videos with a few "squarings then addings" and "bangs for bucks"

Comment: @uhoh yeah I agree, I don't think that answers your question - I was just confirming that, in my experience, Manley often talks in a - shall we say - *inexact* way about somewhat complex concepts ;)

Comment: I think he's talking about the Oberth effect--which for practical purposes says you should do burns as deep in a gravity well as you can.  (The exception being plane change burns, which should be done as far out as you can.)

Comment: @LorenPechtel That's consistent with what I wrote in my [strangely down-voted answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36499/12102) as well.

Comment: @uhoh I was trying to put it in simple terms without the math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite watching a few times it looks like I linked the use of the term "capture" at this point in the video with the use of the term "capture" at `08:20` in the video. But that's about the *mechanical capture* of Snoopy during a docking maneuver and this is about the *gravitational capture* of the combined pair in the Earth's gravitational field.

**What Manley is trying to say is that:**

> If you want to transition from a gravitationally unbound to gravitationally bound status in the Earth's field, this is a manipulation of the energy of the spacecraft's orbit, which depends on position and $v^2$, and a $\Delta v$ impulse can have the largest effect on $v^2$ when
>
> 1. the $\Delta \mathbf{v}$ vector is parallel or antiparallel with $\mathbf{v}$, and
> 2. the speed $v$ is maximum.

And for some further mathematical insight into why this is true, and some intriguing graphical illustrations of this as well, one can read the several excellent answers to [Oberth effect for Earth vehicles](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4229/12102).

Comment: I think this answer is spot-on.

Comment: So I've accepted it for now. I'm happy to consider a different answer though

Comment: All these down votes, but no helpful comments, not even unhelpful ones, and no other answers proposed.

Comment: it's probably because you answered a question before it was deemed well-received. I do like this explanation though, it's not all that... expansive on what he said either so that could be the negatives.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I've never seen that *actually happen*. Voting on questions and voting on answers are usually independent of each other. Something strange is going on here, I think there are five people who see Manley as a minor god and to suggest that his words could be improved-upon may be blasphemy to them.

Comment: @AviCherry that's an interesting thought, thanks. Feel free to comment or even post as an answer in my [meta question](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1303/12102) as well. Thanks! just fyi the answer was posted when there was about three close votes as duplicate to another question where there were no answers that addressed my question. With the window for posting an answer closing rapidly, I added this one.

Comment: @AviCherry Does "[So I've accepted it for now. I'm happy to consider a different answer though](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36494/can-someone-help-scott-manley-explain-this-capture-maneuver/36499?noredirect=1#comment116100_36499)" really give "[people the impression that you're not really interested in what other people might have to say](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36494/can-someone-help-scott-manley-explain-this-capture-maneuver/36499?noredirect=1#comment116529_36499)"? In any event, this theory suggests the voting is not on the quality of the answer.

Comment: Just an fyi I honestly, genuinely, like all of these questions even if theyre extremely specific/not well recieved. I saw a video I wouldntve otherwise here. All of your questions are thought provoking.